# Making Hidden Apps Appear Faded Whilst Sitting On The Dock?

Tags: applications, terminal, dock, macos

Sometimes it can be quite difficult for me to tell which of my apps are hidden on the dock and which are not. Is it possible to make those Apps which I have hidden (either by terminal command or otherwise) to appear as those they have faded into the background whilst sitting on the dock ie to have lowered or reduced opacity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -bool YES && killall -HUP Dock
```

This can be undone with…

```
defaults delete com.apple.Dock showhidden && killall -HUP Dock
```

Comment: This isn't working with a fresh install of Mavericks 10.9.4... Any ideas?

Comment: @kyle This works fine for me in 10.11.5 and I don't remember it not working at any point up to this.